# play audio file synchronously with moving line on graph,MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, plot

I am trying to play audio file along with moving line on a graph....

```
[signal,Fs]=wavread('sig_c.wav');
time=(0:length(signal)-1)/Fs;
figure(1);
plot(time,signal)
grid on;
end_time=length(signal)/Fs;
h=line([0,0],[-0.30 0.30],'Color','r','Marker','o','LineWidth',3);
sound(signal,fs);
tic
t=toc;
while t<end_time
set(h,'xdata',t*[1 1]);
drawnow;
t=toc;
end
```

it play the audio file first and then move the line on the graph.but the result of above is not required one.we need to play the audio file in synchronization with moving line on the graph..

how to do

your help will be appreciated greatly......

Answer (score 1):

you could use the audioplayer for playback instead of sound. So

```
player = audioplayer(signal, Fs);
```

Player is the the audioplayer object (check MATLAB help on audioplayer) which you can play using

```
play(player);
```

While the sound is playing you can do whatever you want. For example there is a CurrentSample property which shows you the sample played at the moment. You can get it

```
c_sample = get(player,'CurrentSample');
```

and use it for your plotting purposes.